# How to reference cell from another sheet in Module - Excel VBA?

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I have a macro in an Excel workbook that updates date from Sheet1 into SQL by clicking a button in Sheet3. Sheet3 also have cells used as parameters during the update process.

Currently, the macro is placed in a module and my SQL statement is as follows:

```
sSQLUpd = "update [table1].[dbo].[Plan] set [Plan_QTY] = " & Plan & "_
           where [MacID] = " & Mac & " and [ModelID] = " & Mdl & " and [Date] = " & dt & "_
           and DATEPART(year,[Date])= " & Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(3, 3).Value & "_
           and DATEPART(month,[Date])= " & Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(3, 6).Value & ""
conn.Execute sSQLUpd
```

But when I test the code I keep getting "Subscript out of range" in my error handler.

The SQL structure is fine, since I tested it by replacing the parts:

```
DATEPART(year,[Date])= " & Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(3, 3).Value & "
```

and

```
DATEPART(month,[Date])= " & Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(3, 6).Value & "
```

with actual numbers and the data can pass.

So it's safe to assume that the codes referencing the cells in Sheet3 have issue. Perhaps it doesn't want to play nice when placed in a module?

I even tried different variations as well:

```
DATEPART(year,[Date])= " & Sheets("Sheet3").range("C3").Value & "
```

No dice....

Anything I can do to modify it?

Comment: Seems silly sometimes, but try putting the value of your Cells into a couple intermediate variables before building up your SQL string. Then use the intermediate variables in the SQL.

Comment: There's definitely a sheet named "Sheet3" ?

Comment: Comment out the error handler and see which line is the problem.

Comment: If that's your exact code the problem is with the line continuation and the improper quotes (syntax highlighting is showing it as well)

Comment: Thanks guys. But I found out what's wrong. Details below. I'm a dumb... : |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait... Never mind. I figured out what went wrong. All I needed to do was change 
Sheets("Sheet3") into Sheet3 only:

```
DATEPART(year,[Date])= " & Sheet3.Cells(3, 3).Value & "
```

Its always the simple stuff that screws with me. :p